# inlining failed in call to unlikely and code size would grow [-Winline] but not using inline

Tags: c++, inlining

very new to C++.

Here is my user defined fmiNode class: (fmi.h)

```
class fmiNode
{
public:
    fmiNode(std::string NodeName,int Address)
    {
        this->name = NodeName;
        this->address = Address;
    }

    std::string GetName()
    {
    return this->name;
    }

    int GetAddress()
    {
    return this->address;
    }

private:
    std::string name;
    int address;
};
```

Here is my main method (fmi.c)

```
int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
  fmiNode node1("NodeA",4);
  fmiNode node2("NodeB",6);
  fmiNode node3("NodeC",8);
  fmiNode node4("NodeD",10);

  while(1)
  {
      MainLoop();
  }
}
```

If I only instantiate one fmiNode object everything is fine. but the following 3 causes a warning to be thrown:

```
 warning: inlining failed in call to ‘fmiNode::fmiNode(std::string, int)’: call is unlikely and code size would grow [-Winline]
```

What am I doing wrong here.

EDIT:

So I should define my class like this:?

```
class fmiNode
{
public:
    fmiNode(std::string NodeName,int Address);

    std::string GetName()
    {
    return this->name;
    }

    int GetAddress()
    {
    return this->address;
    }

private:
    std::string name;
    int address;
};

fmiNode::fmiNode(std::string NodeName,int Address)
{
    this->name = NodeName;
    this->address = Address;
}
```

Cheers,
Rhys

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you define a function (constructor, in your case) inside the class definition, the the result is the same as defining it outside of the class with `inline` keyword, as per the c++ standard:

> 7.1.2.3 A function defined within a class definition is an inline function

So the compiler gets the `inline` hint, but thinks that inlining the constructor into `main` is a bad idea because of the reasons in the warning message, so it gives you the warning.

**Update**: yes, you should define the class as in your *EDIT* to avoid this warning. Better yet, put the definition into the .cpp file to avoid multiple definition errors.

Comment: Thanks. Edited post with what I think should be correct.

Comment: Thanks so much, spent ages searching for an answer! :)

Comment: @Rhys, glad I could help